# Regular Expression is not working with string name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Regular Expression in javascript that is not working. My code is...

**JavaScript :**

```
  function doit()
  {
     var string="something";
     var el=document.getElementById("monu");
     el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(string)/ig,"Everything");
  }
```

**HTML :**

```
    <div id="monu">something is better than nothing</div>
    <button onclick=doit();>replace</button>
```

In function replace if I am using **string** as pattern it is not working.
How can I make it work...any suggestion..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) :

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(string,'ig'),"Everything");
```

Note that if you want to replace a string containing special regex patterns without interpreting them as regex patterns (for example you want to replace exactly `".*"`), then you need to escape your string. There's unfortunately no standard function in JavaScript for that but it's easy to write and find (here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript/3561711#3561711)).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I have one more question suppose I have to replace it with string1 where string1="Everything", what shoud i do in this case..?

Comment: Nice. But, if possible, I would skip the string var and create the var as a RegExp immediatly, to avoid what dystroy mentions in the note. I.e. `var theRE = new RegExp('something', 'ig'); ... el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(theRE,"Everything");`. This also allows you to reuse the regex at lower cost (performance wise).